# In Python, how do I search a TinyDB database for substrings in the values?

Tags: python, string, search, tinydb

I made a database for a project and I want to be able to search the database for the value but better than just a simple == operation. For example, If someone types in "columbia" for the search, I want the dictionary that has "Columbia University " as the value for the "Affiliation" key for that specific person

Comment: http://tinydb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#advanced-queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search using regular expressions:

```
>>> db.search(User.name.matches('[aZ]*'))
>>> db.search(User.name.search('b+'))
```

These correspond to Python's [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) and [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) where the latter searches for an occurenc that may start anywhere in the string.

Alternatively you can use a custom test expression like so:

```
>>> test_contains = lambda value, search: search in value
>>> db.search(User.name.test(test_contains, 'Columbia'))
```

For more details, refer to the [relevant section of the TinyDB docs](http://tinydb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#advanced-queries).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the test_contains example? I've tried this as written and I end up with a NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @AaronCiuffo! The second code example was wrong, it should be fixed now 